# Apple Mach-O linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, include

I'm using Xcode to build a C++ project.

But I don't understand the error message:

"Apple Mach-O linker command failed with exit code 1"

I found that #include is the reason.

I have two .cpp file which include a same .h file. If I remove #include of one, it will be build successfully.

Other header files are fine expect the header file described above. I already used "ifndef".

Answer (score 3):

`#ifndef` include guards only work at the level of the translation unit (usually a single source file).

If you define the same object twice in *two* translation units, that won't be fixed by include guards but the linker will complain bitterly when you try to combine the two object files into a single executable.

I suspect your situation is akin to:

```
hdr.h:
    #ifndef HDR_H
        #define HDR_H
        void rc(void);
        int xyzzy;
    #endif

prog1.c:
    #include "hdr.h"
    #include "hdr.h"
    int main (void) { rc(); return xyzzy; }

prog2.c:
    #include "hdr.h"
    void rc(void) { xyzzy = 0; }
```

In a situation like that, the include guard will prevent the header being included twice in `prog1.c` but it will still be included in both `prog1.c` *and* `prog2.c`, meaning that *each* will have a copy of `xyzzy`.

When you link them together, the linker will not like that.

The solution is to not define things in headers but to merely declare them there, leaving the definition for a C file:

```
hdr.h:
    #ifndef HDR_H
        #define HDR_H
        int rc(void);
        extern int xyzzy;              // declare, not define
    #endif

prog1.c:
    #include "hdr.h"
    #include "hdr.h"
    int main (void) { rc(); return xyzzy; }

prog2.c:
    #include "hdr.h"
    int xyzzy;                         // define
    int rc(void) { xyzzy = 0; }
```

Declarations are things like function prototypes, extern variables, typedefs and so on (simplistically, things that declare something exists without actually creating an "object").

Definition are things that create "objects", like non-extern variables and so on.

You need to track down what "object" is being defined twice (the linker output should have something like `doubly-defined symbol 'xyzzy'`) and then make sure it's not *defined* in the header.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.  Very helpful clarification